# Efficient multiplication of Cayley-Dickson numbers

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, fourier-transform, hypercomplex-numbers

The question was already asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239076/how-quickly-can-we-mutliply-cayley-dickson-hypercomplexes), but doesn't have any meaningful answer, hence I'd like to re-post it.

Assuming that we have an algebra with conjugation, we can use Cayley-Dickson construction to define an algebra on pairs:

$$
(a, b)^* = (a^*,-b), \\
(a,b)(c,d) = (ac-d^*b, da+bc^*).
$$
It is well known that, starting with real numbers, we can construct complex numbers, quaternions, octonions, etc with this. Hence, on $n$-th step we have an $2^n$-dimensional space with this weird multiplication operation defined.

That said, assume that $2$ Cayley-Dickson hypercomplex numbers are represented by a vector of $2^n$ numbers each. Is it possible to compute their product faster than $O(4^n)$, that is, in a sub-quadratic time?

I imagine that some potentially simpler way to do it would be to reduce the multiplication of $2$ numbers to $3$ recursive multiplications instead of $4$, similarly to what happens in Karatsuba and Strassen algorithms, so that the runtime of a single multiplication is $O(3^n)$. One other possibility could be some transform, similar in nature to the fast Fourier transform, that reduces Cayley-Dickson multiplication to a coordinate-wise multiplication in some weird space.

I know for certain that, be the multiplication recursively defined as $(ac+bd, ad+bc)$, there *would* be such a transform, in fact, fast Walsh-Hadamard transform would allow us to compute the whole product in $O(2^n n)$. But I don't see any reasonably simple way to do this for hyper complexes... So, any other ideas?

**UPD**: Per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4629959/319412) (see also the [paper](https://theworld.com/%7Esweetser/quaternions/ps/cornellcstr75-245.pdf)), it's possible to reduce quaternion multiplication to just $8$ multiplications instead of $16$. If a similar formula exists for octonions, it will likely suffice to just apply its transitions recursively.

**UPD 2**: Apparently, the current best [algorithm](https://radioelektronika.org/article/view/S0735272712100056) for octonion product uses $30$ multiplications instead of $64$. It still seems complicated, so it's hard to understand if it generalizes well.

Comment: One big obstruction is that most existing tricks rely on things, like associativity, that are lost as soon as you go to the octonions.  Of course that doesn't rule out the existence of a trick, but it suggests that it won't be one of the standard ones!

Comment: This is true. But Karatsuba-like algorithms might be pretty versatile and don't really depend on associativity, afaik. Apparently, one can reduce quaternion multiplication to just 8 multiplications of real numbers. This makes me a bit optimistic, maybe it's also possible to find some transformations for higher dimension that, even if not linear, would allow to do it in sub-quadratic time.